# AttributeError - 'InterfaceContainer' object has no attribute

Tags: brownie, interfaces, aave

```
from brownie import config, network, interface
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from scripts.get_weth import get_weth


def main():
    account = get_account()
    erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
    # get_weth
    if network.show_active() in ["mainnet-fork"]:
        get_weth()
    # ABI
    # Address
    lending_pool = get_lending_pool()
    print(lending_pool)


def get_lending_pool():
    # ABI
    # Address
    lending_pool_addresses_provider = interface.ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["lending_pool_addresses_provider"]
    )
    lending_pool_address = lending_pool_addresses_provider.getLendingPool()
    # print(lending_pool_address)
    # ABI
    # Address
    lending_pool = interface.ILendingPool(lending_pool_address)
    # return lending_pool
```

######### In **ILendingPool.sol** ########### (link in 1st comment)

I changed the import to:

```
import {ILendingPoolAddressesProvider} from '@aave/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol';
import {DataTypes} from '@aave/contracts/protocol/libraries/types/DataTypes.sol';
```

in order to import them from brownie config:

```
dependencies: 
  - aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@aave=aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1'
```

Comment: I am trying to interact with the Aave lending pool (ILendingPool) and keep getting this error:

AttributeError: 'InterfaceContainer' object has no attribute 'ILendingPool'

ILendingPool interface git: https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPool.sol

Comment: Where does it say you're getting this error

Comment: @PatrickCollins Thank you for your reply!
9:16:00 of the tutorial. 

 lending_pool = interface.ILendingPool(lending_pool_address) - this is the line

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I'm assuming you copied/pasted from OpenZeppelin's GitHub. If that's the case, you may have done what I did and included the GitHub copyright info at the end:

© 2022 GitHub, Inc.
Terms
Privacy
Security
Status

Because of this, your code won't compile and isn't included in the InterfaceContainer. Check and see if that's your issue, I'd bet it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ILending.sol` interface file, especially where you import the `ILendingPoolRegister` and `DataTypes.sol`

YOUR IMPORT IS

> `import {ILendingPoolAddressesProvider} from '@aave/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol'; import {DataTypes} from '@aave/contracts/protocol/libraries/types/DataTypes.sol';`

AND YOUR REMAPPING IN THE CONFIG FILE IS

> remappings:
> `- '@aave=aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1'`

SO THE SOLC COMPILER READS IT AS

> `import {ILendingPoolAddressesProvider} from 'aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol';`

IF THE ABOVE FAILS TRY DOWNLOADING THE AAVE CONTRACTS LOCALLY USING

`npm install @aave/protocol-v2`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the following line:

-->  lending_pool = interface.ILendingPool(lending_pool_address)

If you look at ILendingPool.sol the name of the interface in the file is actually 'IPool' (you're trying to use the filename, not the interface name).

So change it to:

--> lending_pool = interface.IPool(lending_pool_address)

and it should work.